# ZF2 service factory not injected

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I have problems solving a catchable error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Market\Service\UserService::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Market\Mapper\UserMapperInterface,

In the constructor of my `UserService` I use `UserMapperInterface` (dependency injection). I created a factory class for that and I registered it in my `service_manager` config. Nothing is happening and an error is shown.

I created factory and services 19287319827 times but now I don't know how I can solve this noob fatal error.

**Config:**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Market\Service\UserServiceInterface' => 'Market\Factory\UserServiceFactory',
    )
),
```

**Service:**

```
class UserService implements UserServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var object Market\Mapper\UserMappperInteface
     */
    protected $userMapper;

/**
 * UserService constructor.
 *
 * @param UserMapperInterface $userMapperInterface
 */
public function __construct(UserMapperInterface $userMapperInterface)
{
    $this->userMapper = $userMapperInterface;
}
```

**Factory:**

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Market\Service\UserService;

    class UserServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
    {
        /**
         * Create service
         *
         * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
        {
            $userMapperInteface = $serviceLocator->get('Market\Mapper\UserMapperInterface');

            return new UserService($userMapperInteface);
        }
    }
```

I can't believe that I can't solve this noob fatal error. I'm looking and looking for the last 2 hour in my code and I have been checking everything and I think everything looks good but the class is not injected in my factory.

Comment: Change your UserService  constructor to expect the name spaced object. `__construct(Market\Mapper\UserMapperInterface $userMapperInterface)`

Comment: probably a namespace problem. Maybe you are missing a `use` clause in your `UserEsrvice` class

Comment: i have use, PhpStorm automaticly add if miss it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
$userMapperInteface = $serviceLocator->get('Market\Mapper\UserMapperInterface');
```

It probably returns `null` or at least something else then the expected `UserMapperInterface` instance. Since you did not share any code on how and where this `Market\Mapper\UserMapperInterface` is defined or constructed it is hard to say what exactly goes wrong...

Please share more details on that part if you can't figure it out yourself.